# unrecognized selector sent to class when trying to create UIColor

Tags: objective-c, ipad, colors, uicolor

I'm trying to create a custom color out of a hex color code. I have a seperate class called UIColor+Hex, that takes in a hex string and converts it to a color code and returs a UIColor.

UIColor+Hex.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (Hex)

+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hex;

@end
```

UIColor+Hex.m

```
#import "UIColor+Hex.h"

@implementation UIColor (Hex)
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hex
{
    if ([hex length]!=6 && [hex length]!=3)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    NSUInteger digits = [hex length]/3;
    CGFloat maxValue = (digits==1)?15.0:255.0;

    NSUInteger redHex = 0;
    NSUInteger greenHex = 0;
    NSUInteger blueHex = 0;

    sscanf([[hex substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, digits)] UTF8String], "%x", &redHex);
    sscanf([[hex substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(digits, digits)] UTF8String], "%x", &greenHex);
    sscanf([[hex substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2*digits, digits)] UTF8String], "%x", &blueHex);

    CGFloat red = redHex/maxValue;
    CGFloat green = greenHex/maxValue;
    CGFloat blue = blueHex/maxValue;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

I then have UIColor+Hex.h imported to one of my other classes and make a call to it by:

```
[self setSelectedfillColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"FF0000"].CGColor];
```

Whenever I hit this code I get this error...

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIColor colorWithHexString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x873d60'

I've tried everything I could think of but I still keep getting that error. Anyone have any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested your category as you posted and it works fine even with the cgcolor property method. Separate those two lines and make sure the problem is not with setSelectedFillColor. Sometimes the debug errors can be misleading.

Comment: by separate you mean

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"FF0000"];
[self setSelectedFillColor:color.CGColor];

?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that category fine. So I'm thinking the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I wish that was the case but just ried that and still getting the same exception :/

Comment: Alright, the problem is definitely not with the code. Your linking has to be messed up somewhere. Make sure the category is listed in Compile Sources, under the target Build Phases? If you're not adding to target when you add the files maybe that could cause a problem.

Comment: Ok So I readded the two file (.h, .m) but now I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line 

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, selectedfillColor);

this line is inside of the -(void) drawRect method

Comment: Bad Access is usually when you're trying to access an object that is released or not initialized properly. This sounds like an unrelated problem. You should investigate it separately and start a new question if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 7):

Add `-ObjC -all_load` to your Other Linker Flags in your project under the Build Settings.

-ObjC allow the static library to use objective-c specific stuffs like kvc or **categories**.

-all_load solve a bug in gcc/llvm, where -ObjC is not correctly used.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1490.html

Comment: could you elaborate on what this does?

Comment: I've added that to my project yet I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @KonradWinkowski Interesting... Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685497/can-i-use-categories-to-add-class-methods

Comment: seems like the guy is having the same issue but not really getting an answer. I do have the file added to the project and it does compile. Not sure why I keep getting that issue.

Comment: @KonradWinkowski: On that thread the solution was "Hm. After changing the build configuration to release and back to debug, it worked like a charm. Strange." Maybe you can try to restart your Xcode or remove the files and add them again, maybe it will help.

Comment: changed the build configs. still same error.
I'll re-add the UIColor+hex files again and see what happens then.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to add `UIColor+Hex.m` to the Compile Sources list in the Build Phases tab.

The compiler doesn't complain during the build but dies on the selector at runtime.

All too often, it's the missing classes in "Compile Sources" in XCode.